# NelmioApiDoc Bad Request 400 with RestApi

Tags: json, symfony, fosrestbundle

The Nelmio is working perfectly in my project but I get an error `400 Bad Request`

when I want to insert a date in my Nelmio !![image: 400 Bad Request here]

The type used is `Date`.

Comment: Try `datetime` when defining you entity and let me know!

Comment: @aminejallouli Same error display with datetime !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that all the transaction details are not needed as parameters which have to be defined in the URL of you request.

In case of being data, you will have to specify it like this `{"transaction":{}}` in the content box on you right.

Answer (score 1):

you send something like

```
transaction[dateP]=value
```

but form required something like this

```
transaction[dateP][year]=value&transaction[dateP][month]=value&transaction[dateP][data]=value
```

So split your value into 3 parameters or you can change [widget option](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html#widget) of dateP field to `single_text` to solve the problem.